# Выпадающее меню закрывается если кликнуть по нему

Tags: jquery

Написал скрипт, который открывает выпадающее меню и закрывает его при клике в любой части окна или при клике на кнопку, открывающую его. Но проблема в том, что выпадающее меню закрывается по клику на нём, чего быть не должно. Как это поправить?

```
$(function() {
    $('.dropdown').click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('.dropdown-box').toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(window).click(function CloseDropDown(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        var dropdowns = $('.dropdown-box');
        if(!target.is('.dropdown')) {
            dropdowns.each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать новый div, и расположить его поверх страницы, а окно поверх дива:

```
div.overlay{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1000;
}
.dropdown-box{
    z-index:1001;
}
```

И, соответственно, Ваш скрипт повесить не на window, а на клик по этому div, добавив в этот скрипт код удаления созданного div

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropdown-box').click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```